# Ошибка в консоли?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему в консоли при нажатии на стрелку вверх может выдавать ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector') if (parseInt(targetElement.closest('.quantity').querySelector('input').value) <= 1) и как ее можно исправить? Спасибо

```js
const targetBtn = document.querySelector(".quantity__button_minus")

function formQuantity() {
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
let targetElement = e.target;
if (targetElement.closest('.quantity__button')) {
  let value = parseInt(targetElement.closest('.quantity').querySelector('input').value);
  if (targetElement.classList.contains('quantity__button_plus')) {
    value++;
  } else {
    --value;
    if (value <= 1) {
      value = 1;
    }
  }
  targetElement.closest('.quantity').querySelector('input').value = value;
}
if (parseInt(targetElement.closest('.quantity').querySelector('input').value) <= 1) {
  targetBtn.classList.add('disabled')
} else {
  targetBtn.classList.remove('disabled')
}
  });
}

formQuantity();
```

```css
.quantity {
  width: 141px;
  height: 102px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.quantity__arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 53px;
  background: rgba(235, 236, 237, 0.21);
  padding: 25px 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quantity__input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  outline: none;
}

.quantity__input input {
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: math.div(47, 40);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
}

.quantity__button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.quantity__button_plus::before {
  content: '▲';
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #363c43;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.quantity__button_minus::after {
  content: '▲';
  color: #363c43;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.disabled::after {
  content: '▲';
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
  <div class="quantity__input">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="form[]" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="quantity__arrow">
    <button type="button" class="quantity__button quantity__button_plus"></button>
    <button type="button" class="quantity__button quantity__button_minus disabled"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При нажатии на стрелку вверх ошибки нет. Ошибка появляется, если нажимать в пустоту

Comment: До сих пор не понимаю, зачем все эти изврещения с `.closest` :) Нажал, взял `e.target` посмотрел если у него то что тебе надо и дальше запустил ф-ию

Comment: @EzioMercer, потому что таргетом может оказаться не тот элемент, который ты ожидал

Comment: @Grundy В чём проблема проверить у таргета есть то что мне надо или нет?

Comment: @EzioMercer, в том, что визуально пользователь щелкает по кнопке, но target'ом может быть не кнопка. Например, если внутри кнопки есть другие элементы.

Comment: @Grundy Честно, всегда как-то обходил такие проблемы :) Но я понял о чём ты

Comment: @EzioMercer, все зависит от конечной верстки, и если внутри кнопки будет какой-нибудь span с текстом - то код без closest перестанет работать

Comment: @Grundy Не буду спорить с этим :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменения:

- Ограничил поиск только внутри `arrowsBlock`. Если очень надо именно на `document`, то надо будет после `else if` написать `else return;`
- Не надо никаких `closes`. После нажатия у нас уже есть нажатый элемент, можем просто у него смотреть есть ли нужный класс или нет
- `input` можно каждый раз не искать, лучше сохранить и просто потом к нему обратиться
- Убрал ф-ию `formQuantity`, т.к. не вижу в нём смысла. По крайней мере его нет в данном куске кода, если нужно можете добавить - не проблема

```js
const arrowsBlock = document.querySelector('.quantity__arrow');
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.quantity__button_minus');
const input = document.querySelector('.quantity__input input');

arrowsBlock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  let value = Number(input.value);

  if (target.classList.contains('quantity__button_plus')) ++value;
  else if (target.classList.contains('quantity__button_minus')) --value;

  minusBtn.classList.remove('disabled');

  if (value === 0) {
    value = 1;
    minusBtn.classList.add('disabled');
  }

  input.value = value;
});
```

```css
.quantity {
  width: 141px;
  height: 102px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.quantity__arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 53px;
  background: rgba(235, 236, 237, 0.21);
  padding: 25px 12px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quantity__input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  outline: none;
}

.quantity__input input {
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: math.div(47, 40);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
  outline: none;
}

.quantity__button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.quantity__button_plus::before {
  content: '▲';
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #363c43;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.quantity__button_minus::after {
  content: '▲';
  color: #363c43;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.disabled::after {
  content: '▲';
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
  <div class="quantity__input">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="form[]" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="quantity__arrow">
    <button type="button" class="quantity__button quantity__button_plus"></button>
    <button type="button" class="quantity__button quantity__button_minus disabled"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```